# There is an error when try to find the sum of a list

Tags: python, list, sum

The program allow the user to enter any number of numbers to a list but when it get to the part to sum it an error.

```
number_list = [] 



while True:

    number = input('Please enter a number (RETURN/ENTER when done): ')
    if number == '':
        break 
    number_list.append(number)

    
    

for date in range(0,1):
    print("The numbers entered were: ")
    print(number_list)
    print()
    print()
    print('The sum is: ', sum(number_list))
```

Comment: Everything in `number_list` is a string, you forgot to `int()` the number before adding it to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `int` conversion after checking the string wasn't empty. Also `for date in range(0,1):` seems pretty useless, as it iterates once, and you don't use the iteration value, just use the code

```
number_list = [] 

while True:
    number = input('Please enter a number (RETURN/ENTER when done): ')
    if number == '':
        break 
    number_list.append(int(number))

print("The numbers entered were: ", number_list, ', their sum is', sum(number_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Explicit Type conversion to `int` while inserting into the list.

```
number_list = []

while True:

    number = input('Please enter a number (RETURN/ENTER when done): ')
    if number == '':
        break
    number_list.append(int(number))

for date in range(0, 1):
    print("The numbers entered were: ")
    print(number_list)
    print()
    print()
    print('The sum is: ', sum(number_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to convert string to integer. `sum` requires integers. `int()` will help you convert the string to an integer

```
while True:

    number = input('Please enter a number (RETURN/ENTER when done): ')
    if number == '':
        break 
    number_list.append(int(number))
print('The sum is: ', sum(number_list))
```